# Using JIRA Rest API to get a list of all users on a board instead of project?

Tags: rest, jira, jql, jira-agile

Is there a way to do this, or is it even possible to view all users (members of a JIRA board) on the actual application? My workaround for this right now is to query for all issues grab the creators and assignees throw them into a list if they're not already in it. I'd like a more efficient way of doing this, but also this workaround isn't going to work for what I need. Our project has multiple boards, there's one board I'm concerned with and it consists of 10 or so members, the project itself has about 50 members. I know I could query and filter results based on a list, but I'm working on making this applicable across all teams. So is there a way to get a list of users on a board instead of project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIRA Software provides a REST API resource to retrieve all issues of a board: [GET /rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/issue](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board-getIssuesForBoard)

Once you have that list you still have to run over all the issues and retrieve the details of each issue, e.g. by using [GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getIssue). That way you can collect the users that you need.

This still requires some scripting, but should be easy to make this generic so you can support any board.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been doing, calling all issues within a certain time span and then parsing through to get creator and assignee. I think I'm going to feed a csv file instead containing the names I want to look for and filter based on creator = name OR user = name. 

Would you happen to know a better way to get issues instead of using "created" is there an existed keyword in jql or should I use created AND check for status changes?